# phpmyadmin на сервере на ubuntu 18.04 не дает в себя зайти

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

Установлен php 8.1, phpmyadmin, mbstring, gettext, apache2, Mysql подключена, но при попытке зайти по ip на phpmyadmin выдает страницу с таким кодом. В чем может быть проблема? Порты открыл, переустанавливал несколько раз все пакеты, не помогает[image: Открытая страница, перед phpmyadmin - ip сервера]

Comment: В логах сервера причину проблемы проще найти. Создайте php файл любой и пропишите 
```<?php
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```
, посмотрите что выведет.

Comment: Я новичок в Ubuntu, могли бы вы подсказать, как просмотреть потом результат команды, написанной в файле?

Comment: Просто откройте файл в браузере. domain.com/file.php

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что у меня VPS, на котором всё это происходит, извините

Comment: Это что-то меняет?

Comment: У меня есть только открытый IP сервера, домена нет, через IP не получается просмотреть файл

Comment: Файлы, и даже сайты целиком, можно открывать и по прямому ip. Если вы совсем не разбираетесь в администрировании серверов, лучше воспользуйтесь услугами сисадмина. У вас скорее всего просто не запущен php на сервере, поэтому php файлы и не обрабатываются. Либо просто конфиги не настроены.

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам за помощь